# Databricks - wait for delta table change and run job

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I am data analyst, so I have access only to Databricks (creating notebooks and jobs).

I have a delta table which is updated (merging new data) every day. Pipeline is created by administrators. When this table is after update I'd like to trigger notebook or job.

Is that even possible with my access? I tried to create `changeDataFeed` and then what?
I don't get how to move from changeDataFeed to actually trigger something else.

My code snippet (based on different questions):

```
df = spark.readStream \
     .format("delta") \
     .option("readChangeFeed", "true") \
     .option("startingVersion", "latest") \
     .table(tableName) \
     .filter("_change_type != 'update_preimage'")
```

After i query df, streamReader is reading data, but I want to run another notebook or job.

Secondly, I don't want to run this readStream all time, because data is merged once a day (about 7-9 AM).

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **tasks inside the same job** to execute other notebook after your Delta table change.

**This is the sample Notebook Code for the Delta table named as `Delta_Notebook` .**

```
def isdeltaupdated():
    #Your code to check delta table updated or not
    #if updated then we can proceed to run next notebook so return true
    #If not updated then create Value error in this notebook by which the other notebook cannot run
    return False #for sample
if (isdeltaupdated()):
    print("ok")
else:
    raise ValueError("Not updated")
    #Raising error so that it won't run the next task (notebook)
```

First Create a job for this and open that job and go to Tasks of it.

You can see a task is created for the `Delta_notebook`.

[image]

Click on the **+** icon and create another task for the next notebook. Give the **notebook and the dependency 1st task** like below.

[image]

You can see tasks like this.

[image]

Run this Job and you can see that the **second task is not executing when we gave Value error in the First one (Delta table not updated)**.

[image]


[image]

**Second task will be executed if first one won't give any error (Delta table updated)**.

[image]


**First Task:**

[image]

**Second task:**

[image]

You can schedule this Job every day one or two times at a particular time and when Delta table is updated it will execute another notebook.